# PHP verify (). How verify hash pass?

Tags: php, mysql

This authorization code page.
The MySQL database password is encrypted using the "password_hash".

I know that here it is necessary to prescribe "password_verify" but I can not understand how.

This code:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_REQUEST['login_button'])||$_REQUEST['auto']==1){
    require '../_database/database.php';
    $errmsg_arr = array();
    $errflag = false;
    $user_username=   mysqli_real_escape_string($database,$_REQUEST['user_username']);
    $user_password=  mysqli_real_escape_string($database,$_REQUEST['user_password']);
    if($user_username == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'BOO! WHERE LOGIN?';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($user_password == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'BOO! WHERE Password?';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: authentication-check.php");
        exit();
    }
    $sql="SELECT user_username,user_password FROM user WHERE user_username='$user_username'AND user_password='$user_password'";
    $result=  mysqli_query($database,$sql) or die(mysqli_errno());
    $trws= mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($trws==1){
        $rws=  mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['user_username']=$rws['user_username'];
        $_SESSION['user_password']=$rws['user_password'];
        header("location:../home.php?user_username=$user_username&request=login&status=success");    
    }
    else {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'USERNAME OR PASSWORD INCORRECT, RECHECK NOW';
        $errflag = true;
        if($errflag) {
            $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
            session_write_close();
            header("location: ../components/authentication-check.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Retrieve the password from the db using a select against username, then validate the retrieved password against the entered password using password_verify()

Comment: First you need to do a `SELECT` for at least the password column against just the username, i.e. don't add a condition for the password value in your SQL. Then you call `password_verify` with the password the user submitted and the hash you have stored in the database. It will return true or false.

Comment: But don't try to use the password as part of the where clause to retrieve the user record

Comment: And as you're using MySQLi, I'd strongly recommend using prepared statements with bind variables rather than injecting the entered username directly into the SQL query

Comment: thank you very much!! this help:                                                                         $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_username='$user_username'";
        $result=  mysqli_query($database,$sql) or die(mysqli_errno());
        $trws= mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($trws==1){
            $rws=  mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $_SESSION['user_username']=$rws['user_username'];
            $_SESSION['user_password']= password_verify ($user_password,$hash);
            header("location:../home.php?user_username=$user_username&request=login&status=success");

Comment: Mark Baker... how to do it, I do not quite understand???